# How to do slide in/out animation when using flex layout and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, css-animations

I have a layout which uses `flex` to resize its internal components to the window size.

Part of the left column has either some "control buttons" or an "event log" of which visibility can be toggled.

I'd like to animate that show/hide so the log messages div *slides out from the right*.  When the log messages div is hidden, it will *slide back towards the right*.

The system is using AngularJS (not "Angular").

The majority of examples online show how to animate opacity to fade in and out and the few that show sliding animation use `position: relative` wrapping `position: absolute` elements.   However, using `absolute` wrapping `relative` messes up the flex layout: wrong elements are visible and resizing doesn't work properly.

Any idea on how to achieve that effect?

Here is a [fiddle showing the layout](http://jsfiddle.net/v7fLn51y/6/).

Thanks!

[image]